The set of algebraic numbers is countable.
I'm currently working through Rudin's PMA, and I'm on exercise 2.2 which tasks me to prove that the set of algebraic numbers is countable. There is a hint we are given to use, which is that the number of equations that satisfy the equation
$n + |a_0| + \cdots + |a_n| = N$ for any positive integer $N$ is finite. Now, here was my thought process:

Establish a set of $(n + 1)$-tuples consisting of the elements $(n, a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n)$, where $n$ is a positive integer, and $a_i$ is any integer, not all $0$, such that the hint is satisfied; call these sets $C_N$.
Let $P_N$ be the set of polynomials with complex inputs whose coefficients satisfy the above hint. Then $P_N$ is finite.
Let $R_N \subset P_N$ be the set of polynomials that have a root at $z = 0$. Since $P_N$ is finite, then $R_N$ is finite.
Let $A_N$ denote the set of complex numbers that satisfy a polynomial in $R_N$. Since any $n$-degree polynomial has at most $n$ roots, then $A_N$ is also finite.
Take the union of $A_N$ over all positive integers $N$. Then this set is countable, since a union of countable sets is countable.

Please let me know if my logic is right!
Edit: Thank you for the advice removing Step 3. I think I just took an unnecessary, isolating step. This answer would be wrong, since I'm not considering polynomials who have no roots at 0. Thanks a lot for everyone helping!

Why do you have step $3.$?

step 3 is very unusual

Let $f(x)$ denote a polynomial $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$ with integral coefficients. Now all the real roots of $f(x)$ are algebraic numbers.
For every $f(x)$ we associate an integer $N$ defined as $$N=n+|a_0|+|a_1|+\cdots+|a_{n}|$$
Evidently $N\ge1$ and for any given $N$ only a finite number of polynomials have the given value (the given hint).
Each polynomial has atmost $n$ real roots so any value of $N$ can be associated with a finite number of roots.
So now the set of algebraic numbers is the union of roots for each $N$.
So the set of algebraic numbers is a countable union of finite sets so the set of algebraic numbers is countable.
NOTE:
This for the most part agrees with your proof as i understand it except STEP-3

Of course we exclude $f(x)=0$.
